# Is there a way to kill a Pygame sprite without having to kill it in a group?

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

I have a single ball sprite and I don't really have a need for a group. I want to set that sprite to be deleted (or killed) when it reaches the end of the screen, also so it generates another one. I am trying to do this without a group and wanted to know if this is possible. Thank you for your expertise.

I tried self.kill() and kill.self in an update method for the sprite class. That didn't work. I tried to do a kill in the screen update loop for the application. That didn't work. I have done extensive research and all the answer are only when using groups. I also tried to do "if not pygame.surface.rect.contains(Ball())" and that didn't work. (It is something like that, I tried several variations of that expression.)

```
def update(self):
    """Move the ball down"""
    self.y = self.y + 1
    self.rect.y = self.y 
    #print("Screen is: " + str(pygame.surface.rect()))
    print("Object is: " + str(self.rect))
    if (self.rect.y >= 800):
         self.kill()





def update_screen(screen, ball, lamp):
    #Show on the screen
    screen.fill((135,206,250))
    lamp.blitme()
    ball.blitme()
    ballgen(screen)
    ball.update()
    lamp.update()
    pygame.display.flip()
```

I expected the results to stop counting the rect of the ball, but it keeps counting up, thus making me think that it is not being removed.

Comment: Have you considered not killing it and just re-using the same object the next time you need the ball?

Comment: How do I reuse it? I am having it drop and either it will go off the screen or do a collision with the controllable character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use the `Group` class, there's no point in calling the `Sprite.kill` method. All it does is to remove the Sprite from all of its groups. Calling `kill` does not magically remove the `Sprite` from your game.

If you want to have a `Sprite` removed, just stop using it: either stop calling `ball.blitme()` and `ball.update()` in your `update_screen` function, or replace `ball` with a new instance of your Sprite's class.

But consider starting to actually use the `Group` class. It'll make your life easier.

To check if the ball is inside the screen, instead of

```
if not pygame.surface.rect.contains(Ball())
```

use

```
if not pygame.display.get_surface().get_rect().contains(self.rect):
    self.rect.center = (whatever_new_position, ....)
```

in `Ball`'s update method. `pygame.display.get_surface()` will get you the screen surface, `get_rect()` will get you the `Rect` of that `Surface`, and `contains()` will check if the `Rect` of the `Ball` is still inside the screen.

Then we just set a new position for the ball.

Also note that there's usually no need for an `x` and `y` attribute in a sprite class since the position is already stored in the `rect` attribute.

Comment: Thank you! That helped so much. Sorry about the delay, was making adjustments to make it work.